# FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, role

I'm trying to run rake `db:create` with postgresql on a DigitalOcean server.

However, it's returning the error `Peer authentication failed for user "rails"`, referring to `config/database.yml` where the credentials to log in are stored

What's strange is that these are the exact credentials displayed to me in plain text when I log into the server through SSH. I've tried both `<%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>` and the password displayed to me in plain text and the same thing happens.

The environment is in production, which I have to enforce manually because the app is in development on startup and forcing it to change in `config/environments.rb` isn't working.

If I had to guess I might say that something funny is happening with the environment, because DigitalOcean will continue to serve a cached version of the site until the server is restarted and it might still think it's in development as far as it's concerned. But I'm in kind of a catch-22 until I figure out how to force it into production on startup.

This question is what I've arrived at after a lot of tribulation with postgres and trying to set up a database on the backend, so I need to be walked through a couple things.

Many thanks.

Comment: In my case, I forgot specify the host in `database.yml` i.e. `localhost`. By default PG is configured to accept all calls from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is with your `pg_hba.conf` file. Which you can find in `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`. Here 9.3 is postgres version, you can change with your postgres version. More detail about authentication is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-methods.html).

You have code something like :

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER    ADDRESS             METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local    all             all                        peer
```

You can either change it to `md5` or `trust`.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER    ADDRESS             METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local    all             all                        trust
```

It will fix your problem.

**Note :** To edit `pg_hba.conf` file you should have sudo permission on server.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Is that a step backwards in terms of security, though?

Comment: Not working for me... is it necessary to restart PosgreSql server?

Comment: Yes, Sometime you need to restart system also. In never version of postgres 9.4, I have experience we don't need to make any such settings

Comment: @DipakG. Can you tell me that after edit this file from terminal how to save changes. i have same issue i am trying it but my file is not save changes frm me

Comment: To save this file you must have sudo access. You can open file in vim or gedit editor. `sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` or `sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`. gedit provide visual interface so use gedit command. Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: I just tried in PostgreSQL 10.1, it will need to restart psql server after changed.

Comment: Yes restart required on every version, I will update answer. Thanks.