# Not being able to connect to the server using postgresql 11 with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am getting:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Yesterday I had this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992582/running-into-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-with-ruby-on/57993434#57993434) and now running into this one I tried solving it guiding myself with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error), so far I am getting this issues:

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
11  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
```

going into the log file (                                                            /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log                                                             ) I found:

```
2019-09-18 15:26:41.172 CEST [17215] social@postgres DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 90: "local   all             all                                     peer"
2019-09-18 23:01:36.723 CEST [11076] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-09-18 23:01:36.728 CEST [11076] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
```

Trying to access Postgresql will prompt me:

```
sudo su - postgres
postgres@sampc:~$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Trying to start the server I get:

```
$ sudo systemctl start postgresql@11-main
Job for postgresql@11-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@11-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

status:

```
 $service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2019-09-19 13:30:51 CEST; 58min ago
  Process: 26154 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26154 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

sep 19 13:30:51 sampc systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
sep 19 13:30:51 sampc systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

trying **systemctl status postgresql@11-main.service**

```
sep 19 15:13:38 sampc systemd[1]: postgresql@11-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/11-main.pid (yet
sep 19 15:13:38 sampc systemd[1]: postgresql@11-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
sep 19 15:13:38 sampc systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main.
```

journalctl -xe

```
sep 19 16:35:01 sampc CRON[6123]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
sep 19 16:35:47 sampc gvfsd-metadata[1657]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
sep 19 16:35:47 sampc gvfsd-metadata[1657]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
sep 19 16:35:47 sampc gvfsd-metadata[1657]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
sep 19 16:35:47 sampc gvfsd-metadata[1657]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
sep 19 16:35:47 sampc gvfsd-metadata[1657]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
sep 19 16:35:47 sampc gvfsd-metadata[1657]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
sep 19 16:35:47 sampc gvfsd-metadata[1657]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
sep 19 16:35:47 sampc gvfsd-metadata[1657]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
sep 19 16:36:19 sampc nm-applet[1553]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
sep 19 16:36:19 sampc nm-applet[1553]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
sep 19 16:36:19 sampc nm-applet[1553]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
sep 19 16:37:10 sampc nm-applet[1553]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
sep 19 16:37:10 sampc nm-applet[1553]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
sep 19 16:37:10 sampc nm-applet[1553]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
sep 19 16:37:10 sampc nm-applet[1553]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
sep 19 16:37:10 sampc nm-applet[1553]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
sep 19 16:37:10 sampc nm-applet[1553]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
sep 19 16:37:20 sampc sudo[6404]:   samuel : TTY=pts/4 ; PWD=/var/lib/postgresql/11 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod -R 777 main/
sep 19 16:37:20 sampc sudo[6404]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
sep 19 16:37:20 sampc sudo[6404]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
sep 19 16:38:21 sampc xfce4-terminal[2333]: gdk_window_get_window_type: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
sep 19 16:38:38 sampc /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1316]: [3303:3303:0919/163838.578602:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error
```

Comment: You need to do as suggested by systemctl: _See "systemctl status postgresql@11-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details_ to know why the service doesn't start.

Comment: Hi, I have updated with that prompt, sorry I did not add it before.

Comment: `journalctl -xe` is also needed for more details on that error on the PID file.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have updated it

Comment: I couldn't locate the pid file by the way (With:  locate 11-main.pid)

Comment: The `journalctl -xe` output should be captured immediately after the failed attempt to start, otherwise it has only unrelated contents. Although this `/var/cache/samba: Permission denied` makes you suspect that the permissions on /var have been tightened up exaggeratly, and that would be a problem for Postgres, too.

Comment: I changed the permissions to all the subfolders in /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/  with  sudo chmod -R 777 main/  .

Same problem. Updated the journalctl -xe prompt with recent results after attempting to access the rails application again

Comment: uninstalling postgresql and re-installing

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql@11-main
```

worked this time, and it's now running.

I am not sure about what was causing the problem since I did not touch anything ever since the moment it started running yesterday.

Comment: `Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/11-main.pid`: does `/run/postgresql` exist and have the proper permissions so the postgres user can write to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue.
Actually while installing postgres user dont have permission to create files into /var/lib and /var/log so some files are missing. Thats why you are facing issue.

Try to change permission as

- chmod 755 /var
- chmod 755 /var/lib
- chmod 755 /var/log

Then install postgresql again.